# How can I go back to the first view from the third view directly?

Tags: iphone

When I push cancel button in the third view, I want to go back to the first view directly.
I also want to remove the second view.
How can I do that?

This is the code.

```
// this part is in the first view.
self.second = [SecondController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:second.view];

// this part is in the second view.
ThirdController *thirdController = [[ThirdController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];             
self.navigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdController];
[self.view addSubview:navigationController.view];

// this part is in the third view.
- (void)cancel {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview]; // this only goes to the second view.
}
```

EDIT:
Can I use popToViewController in called contoller? My app crashes.
I thought popToViewController can be used only in calling controller.
And popToViewController is used when it was pushed.
I did add not push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`popToViewController:animated:` is a `UINavigationController` method that you use when popping view controllers off the navigation controller stack. It doesn't fit for this scenario.

This user is adding subviews, not pushing them on a navigation controller stack.

As a note, it appears as a matter of design you *should* be using a navigation controller with the first view as the root controller, then the second pushed on the stack, and the third pushed on the stack. Then all you have to do is `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.

I think this will work if you want to keep your current architecture:

```
// this part is in the third view.
- (void)cancel {
    // remove the second view (self.view.superview) from the first view
    [self.view.superview removeFromSuperView];
    // can't recall, possibly you still need to remove the third view, but i think removing the superview will do it.
    // [self.view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

---

If you prefer to try the `UINavigationController` route, then the easiest path is to create a new project in Xcode and select the type for a Navigation-Based Application or a Master-Detail Application. This will create a `UINavigationController` in a nib and add it to your window. You can then set the root view controller in Interface Builder to your FirstViewController class.

If you prefer to create the `UINavigationController` in code, then that is also possible. I show that below, along with the rest of the code you need, regardless of whether you create your `UINavigationController` in a nib in IB or in code.

I also recommend reading the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

In your app delegate or some other code:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions [
    // I would recommend setting up the UINavigationController and FirstViewController as IBOutlets in your nib, but it can be done in code.
    FirstViewController* fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:fvc];

    [window addSubView:navController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [fvc release];
    [navController release];
}
```

In the first view controller:

```
SecondViewController* svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
[svc release];
```

In the second view controller:

```
ThirdViewController* tvc = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc animated:YES];
[tvc release];
```

In the third view controller:

```
-(void)cancel {
    // returns to the first view controller
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: As you told, I want to use popToRootViewControllerAnimated. How can I push second view on the stack?

Comment: I added some sample code to my post. You first need to have a `UINavigationController` that holds the first view controller as the root view controller. Then it's easy to push any number of controllers onto the navigation controller stack, and pop any number of controller off the stack.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

to go back to a specific view controller.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that method doesn't return an `NSArray`.

Comment: Actually it does, from the documentation: "Return Value: An array containing the view controllers that were popped from the stack."

Comment: Can I use popToViewController in called contoller? My app crashes. I thought popToViewController can be used only in calling controller. And popToViewController is used when it was pushed. I did add not push.

Comment: True, you must push in order to pop view controllers.  You might consider pushing instead of just stacking them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

This will pop to the view at index 1. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
// this part is in the third view.
- (void)cancel {
    self.first = [SecondController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:second.view];
}
```

And I think if you have you don't need to be worried about removing beneath view, later these will removed.